# Can I get a university teaching job with only a bachelors degree?

Tags: teaching, career-path

I have a B.Tech (Bachelors of Technology) from IIT Madras (class of 2000) and looking to change tracks from my current job in the software industry. In university, I specialized in computer science and engineering.

I want to know if I can get paid as a faculty for teaching at university level either in private or public universities. I’m also interested to learn what possible salary ranges I should expect.

Comment: It seem to me that this should be a conversation between you and the universities you are applying to teach at. I also do not know what a b.tech is.

Comment: I think BTech is a Bachelor of Technology (please correct me if I am wrong). Udaya, where would you prefer to be employed?

Comment: You can easily get teaching job in any of the private engineering colleges and NITs in India. They will be more than happy to hire you.

Comment: I have edited the question to make the question more clear and direct and to clarify the acronyms. I'm pretty sure I got it right but further edits or comments are welcome.

Answer (score 13):

(U.S. answer follows)

It is virtually impossible to get a teaching job at the college or university level without an advanced degree at the Master's or PhD (or terminal professional degree) level.  Most faculty have a terminal degree.  The opportunities for teaching with a Master's are limited, especially because competition is high and even collegiate level positions that are open to Master's holders still attract PhDs.  Master's degree holders are normally limited to non-tenure track teaching positions and adjunct teaching positions.

If you really do want to be a teacher without an advanced degree, there are opportunities at secondary schools, although most public schools will expect you to start working toward your Master's degree in either Education or your specific field within a few years after you begin.  Private secondary schools are less strict in this regard, but these days you'll find that most teachers will work towards their Master's even in private schools.  With a computer science / engineering degree, you should be competitive for teaching positions in mathematics, physics, computer science/technology, and possibly other sciences.  When I started teaching high school physics, my undergraduate degree was in electrical engineering (but I also finished a Master's in education).

There are obviously exceptions to the above -- Bill Gates could get a job teaching at virtually any school in the country, and he doesn't even have a bachelor's degree.  But, unless you are in a unique category like that, you should be prepared to get an advanced degree of some sort if you want to teach at the college or university level.

Comment: _Bill Gates could get a job teaching at virtually any school in the country_ — [citation needed]

Comment: @JeffE I should have expected that comment! :)  Curious if you disagree. (and I don't believe he would be hired in a CS department; rather, the business school).

Comment: Abdul Kalam (Once was President of India), was denied professorship at IITs, because he was not a Ph.D.

Comment: B.Tech is equivalent to the USA's B.S. I am mostly looking for India jobs

Comment: Additionally, 2-year schools *may* be willing to hire a BS for a teaching position, but most would have a MS and many PhD. It will depend on the school. These institutions have many names in the US, like Junior College or Community College. I am unsure of their counterpart in India.

Comment: Field norms can dictate what makes someone an exception.  Business schools would most likely not have a problem with the lack of a graduate degree for high profile business people.  Art schools have an MFA as a terminal degree, but rarely reject a famous artist based on lack of graduate degrees.

Comment: @JeffE He probably has honorary degrees.

Comment: @Geremia: Those usually don't count.  Jobs that require a PhD usually specify "earned doctorate".

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to get classes as an adjunct instructor at a community college.  I currently have a bachelor's degree in computer science, with no graduate degrees.  I have taught courses as an adjunct instructor in computer science and in developmental mathematics at community colleges in different states.

Answer (score 2):

My Japanese teacher needed to go back to college for a Masters degree, or be forced to leave Santa Barbara community college. Being from Japan gave no leeway in teaching Japanese to beginners. Hence the strictness in the US for a Masters degree to teach at any college level.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a masters degree (at least) to teach university courses. With a bachelor degree however, you might be able to score a position at a highschool considering you've already worked in the industry.Though, if you're really dead-set on giving lectures at university, your best shot would be to pursue a master degree. There are possibilities to study a masters whilst working. You might even be able to teach a bit in highschool whilst studying for your master degree, see what that is like.

Though you might be able to become an assistant instructor, like Herkenham said. Which (here) means that you get to correct students work, give practical lectures (practical coding instead of theory based courses). Once again, having worked in the industry might play to your advantage.

I honestly think having worked in the industry increases your odds, but they are still against you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's sometimes possible to teach at a community college, for example, without a master's degree. I know of one community college that prefers to hire those with a master's degree, but they also accept those with bachelor's degrees + 20 hours of grad-level coursework.

Answer (score 0):

I go to a decently ranked university and some of the lecturers for the first year computer science classes only have bachelor degrees.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, but I think your answer (like many others) is overly broad; a lot depends on the kind of university, its ranking, its country, etc. In many cases, too, the people with bachelor degrees may currently be pursuing a higher degree while teaching.

Answer (score -4):

very bad info here.  ive been teaching for years with no pressure to get a masters.  there's a nationwide shortage for teachers, so why would a masters be necessary?  also you can teach at the college level if the courses are considered prerequisite or remedial/college prep classes.  HS teachers are preferred for these classes as they are acclimated to the type of clientele you can expect in those type's of classes.

Comment: What do you refer to by “very bad info here”? Also consider that your posts are read by sufficiently many people to make your efforts in adhering to the spelling rules worth it.

Comment: Welcome to AC.SE. The question, and our site, is focused at the university level. I am not sure but I do not think there is a nationwide shortage, no matter the nation, of university teachers. In fact, if the competitiveness of the university job market is representative, there is in fact a glut.